# EF6 best practice for loading not mapped fields of an entity tracked by the context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Considering the blogging data model:

```
Blog:
int Id
ICollection<Post> Posts

Post:
int Id
int BlogId
DateTime Date
```

Then loading Blogs with the date of their latest post (LatestPostDate) and bind to the UI, while they are tracked by the context.

There are some solutions, such as using DTO, but the result entities **are not tracked** by the context.
Also I can set the LatestPostDate as NotMapped, define a Table-valued function, and apply SqlQuery on DbSet. Although, the NotMapped fields are not loaded in this way.

What are the best practices?

I try not to add column to the table, also avoid calculating the values after loading.

Comment: DTO(ViewModels) are a best practice (separation of concerns). Use them to craft your views and move them into entities when needed. Automapper is a great helper for this.

Comment: @SteveGreene I think so. Specially because of the Separation of Concerns it is inevitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to handle display concerns in a ViewModel.

But as you do not want to map the Entity to another class, let's first take a look at the `[NotMapped]` variant, using LINQ to calculate the latest post date instead of plain SQL.

```
using System.Linq;

public class Blog {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime? LatestPostDate {
        get {
            return Posts.OrderBy(p => p.Date).LastOrDefault()?.Date;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the value is calculated only when you access the property `LatestPostDate` (probably during UI rendering). You can reduce the number of DB accesses by [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) the `Posts`, although this will increase the size of the data set you are working with.

```
var blogs = _dbContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ToArray();
```

But if you use a ViewModel, you can fill the `LatestPostDate` in one go:

```
public class BlogViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LatestPostDate { get; set; }
}

var viewModels = _dbContext.Blogs.Select(b => new BlogViewModel {
    Id = b.Id,
    LatestPostDate = b.Posts.OrderBy(p => p.Date).LastOrDefault()?.Date;
}).ToArray();
```

Regarding your concerns that the ViewModel is not tracked by the context: in the edit usecase, load the Entity again using the Id provided by the ViewModel and map the updated properties. This gives you full control over the properties that should be editable. As a bonus, the ViewModel is a good place to do input validation, formatting etc.

Comment: I wanted to avoid both solutions. First one results in multiple DB turnarounds which could be done once. The second, needs me to take care of change tracking by means of solutions like EF API and Self-tracking Entity. But I guess there is no way out.